# ODE solver for python respecting periodicity

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a control problem, i.e. an ODE of the form dx/dt = A.f(t), where
x(t) is a function in R^3, f(t) is a function in R^4 and A is a matrix 3x4. In my special case, f(t) = F'(t), i.e. a time derivative of a function F. Furthermore, F is 1-periodic. Hence, integrating the ODE over the interval [0, 1] should yield the starting position again. However, methods like `solve_ivp` from `scipy.integrate` do not respect this periodicity at all (I have tried all the possible methods like `RK45, Radau, DOP853, LSODA`).

Is there a special ODE solver that respects such periodicity to a high degree of precision?

Comment: Could you please give examples on how the periodicity is violated? Do you set `atol, rtol` and compare the values according to these tolerances? // Did you check for errors in the derivative computation? // Can you add a code example to your question (this being SO)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All algorithms will suffer from precision loss anyway, so you will most likely never achieve exact periodicity. Nonetheless, you can also try to increase the precision of the integration by using the parameters "atol" and "rtol", which, roughly, will keep the error of the integration below (atol + rtol*y) at each time step. You can typically go as low as atol=rtol=1e-14.

Comment: While symplectic integrators stay close to an energy surface, they are much less exact in preserving the phase inside the surface. Check for circular motion or, as you cited, planetary motion. The period is only exact within the order of the method. // And where do you recognize a Hamiltonian system in the given task?

Comment: @LutzLehmann indeed, I was mistaken. I edited my answer accordingly, thanks for your comment !

Comment: Thank you, indeed one has to choose `atol` and `rtol` as low as possible. Then, one obtains results at machine precision. Otherwise, in terms of the norm of the curve F, the error interestingly reaches a plateau at 10E-6 for `RK45`and at 10E-8 for `Radau`.

Comment: @mathology maybe try the highest order method 'DOP853'. It is of order 8, while Radau and RK45 are of order 5. This roughly means that, when the time step is ufficiently small, DOP853 will have an error `dt^3` times lower than the 2 previous methods. It is usually better to use the highest order possible when using very low tolerances (~1e-14). You may also find even higher order emthods on Github maybe.
Also, I wonder if using a constant time step (no adaptive time stepping based on error tolerances) such that your period is an integer number of time steps may provide better results.

Comment: For explicit algorithms (not Radau), you can "hack" your way thorugh to impose constant time steps with solve_ivp, by setting atol=rtol=1e+99 (yes) and "max_step"=dt. For implicit algorithms, it won't be a good idea, as atol and rtol are used for the Newton termination criteria and may cause unreasonable behaviours when set to such high values.